# Can i create even spacing between uneven plot points in chart js?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

While plotting a chart in chart js with y axes steps like 0 573 675 900. When i plot it the spacing is between adjacent points are. can i bring the points evenly spaced?

Consider the image

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPbaX.png)

In this image i want the number 7 to appear exactly in the middle and the chart to scale between 1 and 7 and also 7 and 10 accordingly.

Following is a sample code iam working on:

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  var
    example = document.getElementById('example1'),
    hot;

  var headers = ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange", "Pink", 'Brown'];
  var myData = [
    [5, 10, 3, 5, 2, 3, 5, 1],
    [9, 9, 3, 10, 8, 7, 7, 2],
    [5, 1, 10, 6, 7, 9, 4, 8]
  ];
  var StepValues = [1,7,10];
  var rowheaders = ['Mark', 'Anna', 'Diana']

  hot = new Handsontable(example, {
    data: myData,
    rowHeaders: rowheaders,
    colHeaders: headers,
    readOnly: true,
    colWidths: 88,
    licenseKey: 'non-commercial-and-evaluation',
    fillHandle: {
      autoInsertRow: false,
    }
  });


  var options = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: headers,
      datasets: [{
        label: rowheaders[0],
        data: myData[0],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 236, 217)'
      }, {
        label: rowheaders[1],
        data: myData[1],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(235, 224, 255)'
      }, {
        label: rowheaders[2],
        data: myData[2],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(219, 242, 242)'
      }]
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            reverse: false,
            callback: (label) =>{
            if(StepValues.includes(label)){
            return label;
            }
            }
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }

  var ctx = document.querySelector('.chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, options);

});
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: will you please share the code used to draw the chart?

Comment: Please also provide screenshot of your desire output (Because the idea of putting the y value of `7` in the `middle` of range from `0 to 10` sound weird ==> not make sense).

Comment: Putting the value 7 is not my idea , it is a requirement

Comment: Although it is a requirement, this does not make any sense. Charts are suppose to give the user some quick and visual idea of the result. In your case, your scale is neither linear nor logarithmic. I believe you would rethink your approach.

Comment: I requested a deviation to this requirement. So now they are fine with the current implementation